# Зачем при записи чисел в конце добавляют .0?

Tags: javascript, c++, delphi

Часто в коде программ числа записываются в виде цифры с `.0` на конце. Например:

C: `double s = 1.0 / 6.0;`

Delphi: `var d: Single; begin d := 16.0 + 1.0; end;`

JS: `var t = 90.0;`

*Возможны примеры и на других языках, но для начала предлагаю ограничиться этими тремя*

Какой смысл несет добавление `.0` в данных случаях?
В каких случаях `.0` можно опускать, а в каких он меняет логику поведения программы?

Comment: а получится ответить для любого-языка?

Comment: В JS не нужно никогда т.к. в нём нет разделения на integer и float (double). Это просто привычка из Си. В Си для отличия от целых чисел. Например 1/2 = 0, а 1.0/2 = 0.5

Comment: @4per я субъективно указал 3 основных для себя языка. Ответ для них будет достаточным. Тэг любой-язык указан, т.к. поведение в других языках может быть другим и являться интересным дополнением к ответу.

Comment: Ещё один пример из C#: `int.MaxValue + 1` -> `-2147483648`, `int.MaxValue + 1.0` -> `2147483648`

Comment: @VladD, приведется к double? :-)

Comment: Замечу, что необязательно добавлять `.0`, вполне может хватить и просто точки `.` (по крайней мере в си).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если говорить в общем, то добавление `.0` к числу, **изменяет его тип** и превращает его из **целого**, в **дробное** (число с плавающей точкой). Такое изменение типа числа влияет на то, как оно будет храниться в памяти и на то, как и какие операции с ним могут выполняться.

В JS добавление `.0` абсолютно лишено всякого смысла, т.к. там все числа изначально являются дробными.

В Delphi так же не возникает необходимости вручную приводить целые числа к дробным, т.к. компилятор замечательно справляется с этим самостоятельно, там где это нужно. Операция деления двух целых всегда возвращает дробное число и его невозможно по ошибке присвоить целому. Для особых случаев, когда надо выполнить целочисленное деление, есть специальный оператор `div`.

А вот в Си и некоторых других языках, и для целочисленного, и для обычного деления используется один и тот же оператор деления `/` который ведёт себя по разному, в зависимости от типа операндов:

- если оба операнда целые, то и в результате деления будет целое (целочисленное деление): `double i = 5 / 2;` даст `2.0` (дробная часть результата операции отбрасывается, получается целое число, которое затем приводится к целевому типу `double`).
- если хоть один из операндов является дробным, то и результат будет дробным: `double i = 5 / 2.0;` даст `2.5`.

В Си, вместо `.0` перед числом можно указывать тип числа с плавающей точкой (`float`/`double`), т.е. выполнять приведение типа: `double i = 5 / (double) 2;` такая конструкция используется, если операнд не число, а переменная целочисленного типа:

```
int k = 2;
double i = 5 / (double) k; // --> i = 2.5
```

Comment: _изменяет_ не совсем корректно. Так как это литерал, у него нельзя что-то изменить. возможно лучше _указывает_?

Comment: @Grundy По-моему, всё корректно. Литерал изменяет программист, изменяя тем самым его тип и превращает его из ... в ...

Answer (score 8):

В конце литерала нужно добавлять `.0` в том случае, если вам важно получить тип с плавающей точкой. Я приведу пример для С/С++, но он также будет актуальным для Java, C# и многих других языков:

`double X = 15 / 2;   // Выведет 7`

Здесь тип переменной - `double`, так что можно подумать, что в ответе получится 7.5, но это не так. Поскольку и `15` и `2` не имеют дробной части, они будут считаться целыми числами при вычислении, и для них сначала будет произведено целочисленное деление (`15 / 2 = 7`), а потом полученный результат будет конвертирован и записан в переменную типа `double`.

Это можно исправить, добавив пустую дробную часть к одному или к обоим литералам. Если один из операндов является числом с плавающей точкой, то второй операнд тоже будет конвертирован в число с плавающей точкой, и вы получите правильный результат:

`double X = 15.0 / 2;   // Выведет 7.5`

**Общее правило для C++ и подобных языков:** добавляйте `.0` к литералам тогда, когда ожидаете ответ типа `float` или `double`. Это поможет избежать неожиданностей.

Comment: Для Delphi поведение будет иным, т.к. оператор деления, например, не имеет целочисленного варианта и всегда отдает число с точкой. То есть получается это зависит и от поведения операторов и от поведения присвоений тоже.

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо за уточнение!

Comment: @Kromster Но я должен сказать, что я не знаю ни одного языка, где операция `15.0 / 2.0` дала бы целочисленный результат, поэтому я думаю, что общее правило будет справедливо и для языков вроде Delphi: если вы ждете в ответе число с плавающей запятой, то имеет смысл добавить `.0` к целым операндам.

Comment: Тогда наверно стоит обозначить это как пример защитного программирования.

Comment: @EugeneMagdalits, в Delphi для целочисленного деления отдельный оператор

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, тогда я внесу в ответ соответствующие изменения.

Comment: Для `float` следует указывать суффикс `f` или `F`. А ещё Вы забыли о `long double` (`l` или `L`).

Answer (score 1):

.0 задавать для значения переменной нужно для того, что бы явно показать как компилятору (интерпретатору) языка, так и программисту, что в контексте использования переменной речь идет о дробных числах. Один из возможных примеров   [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16221776/6935496).

1. Изучайте базовые типы и приемы работы с переменными этих типов для тех платформ и языков, на которых программируете или собираетесь начать программировать.
2. Если у вас есть вероятность, что в результатах ваших вычислений будут задействованы дробные числа - так и работайте с переменными соответствующих типов.

Comment: Будет ли то же справедливо для C например, в записи вида `double s = 1 / 6`, не произойдет ли вычисление выражения в целочисленном виде с присвоением результата в число с точкой? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776)

Comment: Произойдёт. Поэтому ответ явно неполный

Comment: Дополнил ответ (постарался не привязываться к конкретному языку).

Comment: Мдя. Нужно тогда когда нужно. Бессмысленная добавка

Comment: @AlexeyTen, перефразировал более лаконично.

Comment: NB: целочисленные типы есть не везде.

Answer (score 1):

В давние времена, когда появился Fortran - первый язык программирования высокого уровня, имеющий транслятор, это были азы, с которых начиналось обучение программированию.
Добавление точки после числа сейчас называют неявным приведением типа.
Когда надо было получить тип REAL от деления целых, писали Z=(X+0.)/(Y+0.)
или Z=7./8.

Это, конечно, было неисчерпаемым источником багов в программах.
Тогда считалось несолидным добавлять ноль после точки.
Это же целая лишняя дырка в перфокарте!