# При делении чисел пропадает дробная часть

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Я делю два числа друг на друга, например `1 / 2` и ожидаю получить в результате `0.5`, так как присваиваю результат переменной с плавающей точкой, но получаю `0`. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double d = 1 / 2;
    std::cout << d << "\n";    
}
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Зачем при записи чисел в конце добавляют .0?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577860)

Comment: @zed о. Я даже там в комментариях отметился давненько.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Дело в том, что в C++, а равно как и в C, C#, Java и многих других языках деление целых чисел даёт исключительно целый же результат, т.е. дробная часть просто отбрасывается.

Стандарт языка буквально так это и говорит [[expl.mul]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4):

> For integral operands the `/` operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;

Подобное поведение обусловлено в первую очередь производительность, т.к. целочисленная арифметика обычно работает быстрее арифметики с плавающей точкой.

То, что результат деления целых чисел присваивается переменной с плавающей точкой не влияет на само деление, т.к. присваивание выполняется уже после факта деления. И мы просто инициализируем вещественную переменную `d` целым значением `0`, которое никак не даст нам чего-то с ненулевой дробной частью, например, ожидаемых `0.5`.

Чтобы всё-таки добиться желаемого результата нужно производить *вещественное* деление. Для этого достаточно хотя бы один из операндов привести к вещественному типу. Сделать это можно разными способами. Если используется константа, то достаточно дописать в конце неё точку, например:

```
double d = 1 / 2.;
```

или

```
double d = 1. / 2;
```

Это выглядит минималистично, но иногда несколько странно, т.к. в математике подобная запись не используется. Для большей наглядности стоит добавить `.0`, получим:

```
double d = 1.0 / 2;
```

Если вместо явного числового литерала используется именованная целочисленная переменная, или функция, возвращающая целый тип, то добавлением точки с нулём проблему уже не решить, и нужно выполнять иное приведение типа, т.е. делать `static_cast`:

```
int one = 1;
int two() { return 2; }
double d = static_cast<double>(one) / two();
```

Но можно использовать и умножение (или деление) любого операнда на `1.0`, что так же преобразует результат, который будет выступать операндом последующего деления, к вещественному типу:

```
double d = (one * 1.0) / two();
```

Альтернативным вариантом может быть прибавка (или вычитание) вещественного нуля:

```
double d = (one + 0.0) / two();
```

Однако, вариант со `static_cast` будет более правильным, т.к. такие преобразования всегда легче находить в тексте программы, нежели обычные плавающие константы.

Ну и конечно же, если речь идёт о переменных или функциях, то можно просто изменить их тип:

```
double one = 1;
double two() { return 2; }
double d = one / two();
```

В такой ситуации надо не забывать, что использование `one` и `two` в других контекстах так же может давать иные результаты, что были раньше. Поэтому задачу всё же лучше локализовать, и не делать всё поголовно в программе вещественного типа, если это требуется только в некоторых частных случаях.

Comment: Можете добавить еще `(1 + .0) /  2` и аналоги. Хорошо тем, что работает аналогично касту к плавающему типу  и с переменными тоже (хотя, аналогичный пример с умножением на 1.0 уже и был).

Comment: @avp добавил и такой вариант. Про `log(exp(N))` добавлять не буду :)

Comment: А как же `(double)one`?

Comment: @Qwertiy ¡C no pasarán!

Answer (score 0):

Здесь  происходит деление целых чисел тобишь  int

А потом присваивается значение double

Таким образом мы знаем что 1/2 = 0,5 , а в int это 0 поэтому и выводит 0 .