# Вычисление корня произвольной степени

Tags: c++, математика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как извлечь корень произвольной степени из числа. Пример:

> [image: Пример:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Извлечение корня степени *n* из положительного числа равносильно возведению в степень *<sup>1</sup>/<sub>n</sub>*. Так что всё просто:

```
pow(a-b, 1/(c+1));
```

О чём ещё следует помнить:

- Если нужно обрабатывать отрицательное подкоренного при нечётных степенях корня, то  обрабатывать знак придётся вручную.
- Если `c` — целочисленная переменная, то [не забудь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726773/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/726774#726774) поставить в числитель вещественную константу, например `1.0` или привести `c` к `double`.

Comment: чтобы не приводить `c` к `double` вручную, можно единичку сделать `double`: `1.0 / (с + 1)`

Comment: @Croessmah [и не только](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726774/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я за самый простой вариант ))

Comment: @Croessmah тогда 0 можно убрать

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а это уже личное.