# 100/1000 = 0 , а должно же быть 0.1

Tags: c++

```
float res = 100 /1000;
    std::cout << res;
```

в консоль выводи 0 , а должно 0.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как это иправить

Comment: [При делении чисел пропадает дробная часть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726773)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что вы делит целой число на целое. то что вы сохранили в float ничего не меняет. надо одно из чисел превратит в float добавив точку в конце

```
float res = 100. /1000;
std::cout << res;
```

Как сказал gbg добавление точки в конце создаёт число типа double, а не float. Чтобы создать именно float надо место просто точки написать `.0f`

```
float res = 100.0f /1000;
std::cout << res;
```

Comment: Добавление точки в конец числа говорит компилятору о том, что это число имеет тип double (и заставляет компилятор делать лишине шевеления). Правильно писать 100.0f - тогда это точно будет float

Answer (score 3):

целое разделить на целое равно целое :)

надо показать компилятору, что делите не целые числа

```
float res = 100.0 / 1000;

float res = 100 / 1000.0;

float res = 100.0 / 1000.0;
```