# Задача с вкладом

Tags: c++

Решаю такую задачу:
Вклад в банке составляет **x** рублей. Ежегодно он увеличивается на **p** процентов, после чего дробная часть копеек отбрасывается. Определите, через сколько лет вклад составит не менее **y** рублей. 
Тестирующая система говорит что слшком долго, вероятно если **x** намного меньше **y**. Как можно оптимизировать?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x, p, y;
cin >> x >> p >> y;
int i = 0;

while (x < y) {
    x += (x * p / 100);
    i++;
}

cout << i;
}
```

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: 1) Приведите входные данные, и что ожидаете получить. 2) `x / 100` <- тут деление целочисленное.

Comment: @wololo ввод: 100 10 200, вывод: 8. но из-за того что прибавляется всегда 10 выводит 10

Comment: `100` -> `100.0`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При делении чисел пропадает дробная часть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726773/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @wololo отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача линейная (ключевое слово - логарифм). И считать надо сразу в копейках (введенные рубли перевести в них), тогда не надо будет отбрасывать дробную часть копеек.