# Ошибка при делении

Tags: c++, деление

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int ages[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cin >> ages[i];
    }
    
    int min = ages[0];
    for (int a = 1; a < 5; ++a){
        if (min > ages[a]) {
            min = ages[a];
        }
    }
    
    cout << 50 - (50/100)*min;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Всё нормально до тех пор, пока очередь не дойдёт до деления, выдаёт просто 50 при любых значениях, а такого быть не должно.
Друг посоветовал использовать вместо деления на 100 - умножение на 0.01, и да, так код заработал как положено, но мне всё равно интересно, почему оно не делит как положено и приходится применять умножение?

Comment: ¿Какой результат вы планируете получить при выполнении `50/100`? ¿Какой результат реально видите в отладчике?

Comment: `int` деленый на `int` выдает `int` - дробная часть отбрасывается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При делении чисел пропадает дробная часть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726773/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При целочисленном делении вы получаете целочисленный же результат, т.е. `50/100` равно `0`.

В данном случае одна точка решит все проблемы:

```
cout << 50 - (50./100)*min;
```